# Node 8.10.0 error “Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode”

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am starting in a new project that is almost done. I installed the Node version 8.10.0 and it throws an error in the browser console:

> Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode

```
settings: {
   purchaseAmount: null,
   pendingTime: 500,
   validationResult: !0000
}
```

the error is on the line 31 which contains: `validationResult:!0000`

Do you know what could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Prefixing a number with `0` tells JavaScript to interpret as an octal number.

Your `validationResult` really should be set to `true`.